# Deviate vs. Variable

Tags: random-variable, definition

What is the difference between a multivariate normal random deviate and a random variable?  More specifically, I suppose, what exactly is a deviate?

Comment: I added the relevant tag `random variable` and removed the tags `variance` and `standard-deviation` which don't directly relate to the question. A random variable might have a multivariate normal distribution, or it might (and typically will) have some other distribution. 'Deviate', as Dimitry suggests, tends mostly to be reserved for an outcome of a random variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that a deviate/variate a particular outcome of random variable. If I generate a 100 draws from standard normal (a random variable) using my favorite PRNG, I get 100 [standard normal deviates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_deviate).

Comment: I've always regarded _normal deviates_ as an oxymoron that has been perpetrated by statisticians as an inside joke.After all, in pop psychology, some peop[e are normal, and any one who is not normal is a deviate!  More seriously, to me a deviate suggests a sample value of a _zero-mean_ random variable; the numerical value is the _deviation_ from the mean.  But then, what do I know? I am neither a statistician nor a psychologist, or for that matter, a linguist or lexicographer.

Answer (score 2):

The terms "variate" and "deviate" appear to be interchangeable:

> a random variable is a measurable function from a probability space to a measurable space of values that the variable can take on. In that context, and in statistics, those values are known as a random variates, or occasionally random deviates[1]

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variate (3/8/2018)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/196819)

Comment: Thaks @Ferdi.  Edited.

Comment: More tersely, a random variate is an element of the image of a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

A variable (singular) can and usually does vary. A variate (singular) never varies - it is a realisation, a raw value. A deviate is the output of a calculation, not a raw datum. As the name suggests, every variate becomes a deviate once subtracted from the mean, for example. The deviate-du-jour divided by the average deviate is the T statistic. ie The SNR.

Comment: What does *SNR* stand for?